# How to get expo ejected react native app to request bundle from metro?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've inherited a React Native project that was completed a couple of years ago. The react-native version is 0.58.4. I can't figure out how to debug the JavaScript files.

This was originally an Expo project but was ejected to a bare RN project before I got my hands on it.

I've been able to build the app and install it on both a simulator and an actual device, but the app never requests the bundle from metro and I'm not able to bring up the developer menu.

The metro bundler does launch and entering `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false` in a browser window results in a request to the metro bundler and a download of the js file to the browser window. So the problem appears to be that the app never makes a request to the metro bundler.

I can bring up the familiar React Native Debugger web UI, but neither shaking the physical device, or pressing CTRL-R in the simulator have any effect.

[image: rn debugger screen]

To install to the device, I'm having to build the bundle with this command, which I understand is how a release bundle is built.
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false--entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

And then I install it on the device/simulator with this command
`react-native run-android`

I've tried not creating the bundle first (the app launches and immediately crashes).
I've tried Googling (A LOT) but I'm not sure I'm asking the right questions.

I'm really out of ideas. Any help getting the app to request the bundle from metro and enable debugging of the JavaScript files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you installed react-native-cli ?

Comment: Actually I didn't. That helped with running ```react-native run-android``` w/o specifying the node_modules directory. Thank you for mentioning it - I guess I had tunnel vision. It did not help with the debugging issue though.